# Is Tiger/Line 2010 Data Inaccurate? What's more reliable?

Tags: tiger

I followed the instructions at:
http://www.letseehere.com/postgis-geocoder-using-tiger-2010-data

To get postgres working with postgis, but some of the addresses are off 500 ft to as much as 1 mile in my random sampling. Do you know of any more reliable data sets?

Comment: Tiger/Line is only as good as the data submitted to it; there are commercial vendors (TomTom/TeleAtlas or Nokia/Navteq) that are much more accurate but also will cost you several thousands of dollars. For free geocoding/routing of data your good choices are highly limited.

Comment: @D.E.Wright Seems a better answer than comment. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tiger/Line is only as good as the data submitted to it; there are commercial vendors (TomTom/TeleAtlas or Nokia/Navteq) that are much more accurate but also will cost you several thousands of dollars. For free geocoding/routing of data your good choices are highly limited.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for other geocoding data sources, you would probably benefit by searching and reading previous discussions on this site (with the tag [[geocoding]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geocoding?sort=votes)), but a couple specifics I would recommed reading are:

- [Geocode quality: Nominatim vs. PostGIS Geocoder vs. Geocoder::US 2.0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7271/geocode-quality-nominatim-vs-postgis-geocoder-vs-geocoderus-2-0)
- [Is there an open source Geocoding tool which can be used commercially?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18871/is-there-an-open-source-geocoding-tool-which-can-be-used-commercially)
- [Geocoding that's anonymous, good, and free - does it exist?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6/geocoding-thats-anonymous-good-and-free-does-it-exist)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a ready to run server with all TIGER 2013 data loaded as Amazon AWS Server (AMI). See here: http://www.tigergeocoder.com/. I found it to be pretty good, TIGER data improved a lot from 2011 edition. 2012 and 2013 are pretty good data wise.